# Uploading Image Problem Ant d, Next.js and Express.js

Tags: reactjs, express, antd, next.js13, next.js14

I try to use antd image uploading component in my next.js 14 project. When I upload my formData I got req.file undefined in my backend(express.js).But when I try  to postman and I got value in req.file in backend. Frontend image file I got imgUrl:file. So Problem is Backend  req.file got undefined when I post it my frontend How to solve it /?

frontnd code :

```
"use client";
import { Button, Checkbox, Form, Input, Upload } from "antd";
import { PlusOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { ColorChange } from "../../utls/ColorChange";
import { Dancing_Script } from "next/font/google";
import Link from "next/link";
import { authService } from "@/app/fetch";`


const inter = Dancing_Script({ subsets: ["latin"] });

function FormSignUp() {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

 const onFinish = async (values: any) => {

  console.log(values);
  const formDataToSend = new FormData();

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(values)) {
    if (key !== "imgUrl") formDataToSend.append(key, value);
  }
  formDataToSend.append("imgUrl", values.imgUrl);

 formDataToSend.forEach((value, key) => {
   console.log(`${key}:`, value);
 });

 const value = await authService.signup(formDataToSend);
 };

 return (
 <div className="my-10">
  <div className={inter.className}>
    <p className="text-center text-4xl font-bold text-red-600 my-4">
      Sign Up Form
    </p>
  </div>
  <div className="mx-20">
    <Form
      //   {...formItemLayout}
      form={form}
      name="register"
      onFinish={onFinish}
      initialValues={{}}
      //   style={{ maxWidth: 600 }}
      scrollToFirstError
      layout="vertical"
      encType="multipart/form-data"
    >
      <Form.Item
        name="nickname"
        label={<span className="signupTextColor">Nickname</span>}
        tooltip="What do you want others to call you?"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input your nickname!",
            whitespace: true,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        name="email"
        label={<ColorChange>E-mail</ColorChange>}
        rules={[
          {
            type: "email",
            message: "The input is not valid E-mail!",
          },
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input your E-mail!",
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        name="password"
        label={<ColorChange>password</ColorChange>}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input your password!",
          },
        ]}
        hasFeedback
      >
        <Input.Password />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        name="confirm"
        label={<ColorChange>Confirm Password</ColorChange>}
        dependencies={["password"]}
        hasFeedback
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please confirm your password!",
          },
          ({ getFieldValue }) => ({
            validator(_, value) {
              if (!value || getFieldValue("password") === value) {
                return Promise.resolve();
              }
              return Promise.reject(
                new Error("The new password that you entered do not match!")
              );
            },
          }),
        ]}
      >
        <Input.Password />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        name="imgUrl"
        label={<ColorChange>Image Upload</ColorChange>}
        rules={[
          {
            type: "object",
            message: "Image issues!",
          },
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input Image!",
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Upload maxCount={1} listType="picture-card">
          <div>
            <ColorChange>
              <PlusOutlined />
              <div style={{ marginTop: 8 }}>Upload</div>
            </ColorChange>
          </div>
        </Upload>
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        name="agreement"
        valuePropName="checked"
        rules={[
          {
            validator: (_, value) =>
              value
                ? Promise.resolve()
                : Promise.reject(new Error("Should accept agreement")),
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Checkbox>
          {
            <ColorChange>
              {" "}
              I have read the <a href="">agreement</a>
            </ColorChange>
          }
        </Checkbox>
      </Form.Item>
      <div className="flex justify-between">
        <Form.Item>
          <Button
            className="text-red-700 border border-red-500 hover:text-green-700 "
            htmlType="submit"
          >
            Register
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
        <Link
          className="text-end text-xl text-red-700 underline "
          href="/login"
        >
          {" "}
          Go to login now!
        </Link>
      </div>
     </Form>
     </div>
    </div>
    );
   }

   export default FormSignUp;`
```

backend code:

```
 const signupController = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.file)
  console.log(req.body)

   res.send(req.body)

  });
```

Multer code:

```
import multer from "multer";
import path from "path";

 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
  cb(null, "public/temp");
     },

 filename: function (req, file, cb) {
 const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
 cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + uniqueSuffix + file.originalname);
 // cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix + file.name)
 },
 });

 const uploader = multer({
 storage,
 fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
 const supportedImages = /png|jpg|jpeg|gif/;
 const extensions = path.extname(file.originalname);

 // const extensions =path.extname(file.name)
 console.log("eeekoi img", file.name);

 if (supportedImages.test(extensions)) {
   cb(null, true);
 } else {
  cb(new Error("Must be png|jpg|jpeg|gif"));
 }
  },
  limits: {
 fileSize: 5000000,
  },
  });

 //   const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

  export default uploader;
```

Comment: Please check developer console, network tab you will see what posted to backend.